# Pandas: how to use query to select closest values

Tags: python, pandas

I'm using Pandas 0.13.0 and I try to get the two closest values as follow.

The index is sorted with increasing and unique values.

```
import pandas as pd
import Quantities as pq

f = { 
    'A': [ 0.0,  0.1,  0.2,  0.5,  1.0] * pq.m,
    'B': [10.0, 11.0, 12.0, 15.0, 20.0] * pq.kPa,
    'C': [  a1,   b1,   c1,   d1,   e1]        
}

df = pd.DataFrame(f)

df.set_index(df['A'], inplace=True)
```

The DataFrame gives:

```
in: print df

out:
      A       B         C
A                 
0.00  0.00 m  10.0 kPa  a1
0.10  0.10 m  11.0 kPa  b1
0.20  0.20 m  12.0 kPa  c1 
0.50  0.50 m  15.0 kPa  d1
1.00  1.00 m  20.0 kPa  e1
```

I have a value that is not in the column A: `value_to_find = 0.15 m`.
This value changes during the process, so I cannot hard code it.

I try to find the best way to get the first value `just before` and the value `just after` `value_to_find` in the column `A`, and then return column `A` and `B`. And then interpolate value_to_find to get the `B` value.

Result would after filtering:

```
      A       B       
A                 
0.10  0.10 m  11.0 kPa
0.20  0.20 m  12.0 kPa
```

---

One way to select the right values before interpolating is:

```
filter_before = '%s <= %f' % ( 'A', value_to_find)
filter_after = '%s >= %f' % ( 'A', value_to_find)
```

Then:

```
df_before = df.query(filter_before)
df_after = df.query(filter_after )

value_before = df_before.loc[df_before['A'].idxmax(), ['A', 'B']]
value_after = df_before.loc[df_before['A'].idxmin(), ['A', 'B']]
```

---

Is there any better way to do it? Maybe using query, map or something similar.

like: `filter_before = '%s <= %f | max(%s)' % ( 'A', value_to_find)` (this one doesn't work for me)

Thanks.

Comment: Edit: fix typo in operator `>=` (before it was `=>`)

Comment: Interpolation is your friend http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.interp.html

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your answer. Yes you're right, but it does not play well with quantities. Or at least I didn't found how.

Comment: I am not sure what you mean with quantities. I guess that's your notion of using also units rather than just numbers. However, I wouldn't mix the concepts here. Keep the units in the name of the column. What prevent's you from using m in your first row and m*m in the second row, etc.  If you are using plain numbers you can easily call interpolate and you will have numerous options at hand for that....

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Unless I misunderstood your question I get output you wanted without using `query`:

```
value_to_find = 0.15
Min = df['A'] <= value_to_find
Max = df['A'] >= value_to_find
idx_Min = df.ix[Min, 'A'].idxmax()
idx_Max = df.ix[Max, 'A'].idxmin()
df.ix[idx_Min:idx_Max, ['A','B']]

       A   B
A           
0.1  0.1  11
0.2  0.2  12
```

I did not use `Quantities` module but this should not play a role here.
Indeed if you get to find an exact match to `value_to_find` there will be only one line in the output.

Comment: Hi, yes that's a better and simpler approach than mine. Thanks a lot for your answer.

Comment: this is linear time search. given the index is sorted, is there any way to use pandas' built-in functionality to perform a faster (binary) search?

Comment: Not sure what you mean by 'binary' search, but the last line (in code of my answer) is all you need to use built-in methods if you want to access `pandas.DateTimeIndex` directly. The problem the OP had is to get those indexes first. If you feel I misinterpreted your comment it might be worth to ask it as a separate question (assuming you have read [the docs on indexing `DateTimeIndex`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/timeseries.html))

Comment: I use this method to searching using two values: `df.ix[idx_Min_column0:idx_Max_column0].ix[idx_Min_column1:idx_Max_column1]
`